# mongodb c#: multi doc update with a fixed size

Tags: c#, mongodb

Lets say we have a collection named "things" where "thing" is a document like this :

```
thing : {
    field1 : value1,
    field2 : value2,
    ...
    fieldn : valuen,
    someDate : dateValue
}
```

Using c# (the official driver) we can update multiple documents on the collection "things" by doing this:

```
things.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

The question: is there a way to order "things" by the 'someDate' field and then take a fixed number of document to update ?

something like :

```
things.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi).orderby('somedate').take(1000)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to find a criterion that matches whatever documents you want to update. For instance, if your documents have an ObjectId as `_id` field, you could do this:

```
var highId = things.Find(query).SetSkip(1000).First().Id;
```

and then do an update like this:

```
things.Update(Query.And(Query.<Thing>.LTE(p => p.Id, highId), otherCriteria),
              update, UpdateFlags.Multi)
```

That will, however, also update any documents that have been inserted very recently, i.e. between the query and the update statement. You could also query for the first and last `_id` and use a `GT / LTE` pair.

Naturally, some monotonic key (like an ObjectId or a timestamp) is required for this to work.

Also keep in mind that the timestamps are generated by the clients, so expect some clock skew.

Comment: This is an interesting "hack", could be the solution for my problem. however it supposes that the _id field is incremented for each doc inserted. but we could also have some deletions.

Comment: im afraid your solution is best way to do it. ill wait a little before marking it as an answer. thank you.